istreambuf_iterator potential null pointer deref
In the following code:
std::string fn()
{
    std::ifstream ifs {"bob", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary};
    auto beg = std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs);
    auto end = std::istreambuf_iterator<char>();
    std::string ret {beg, end};                    // ERROR
    return ret;
}

int main ()
{
    std::cout << fn() << std::endl;  
}

I get a potential null ptr deference error (warning turn into an error). See full example with error: https://godbolt.org/z/PosGM8oKo
Assuming that the file "bob" exists and has been checked for existance. I am not quite sure how to solve this one.
In here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator/istreambuf_iterator
It says the c'tor for beg iterator:

Initializes the iterator and stores the value of is.rdbuf() in a data member. If is.rdbuf() is null, then end-of-stream iterator is constructed.

So I added the check:
if (beg == end)
    return "";

before I construct the return string - but that did not resolve the warning. I think that is the problem area, but I can't see how to sort it.
Note:
The warnings I am using are:
 -Wall -Wextra -Wnull-dereference -Wconversion -Werror -Wpedantic -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion
I am wandering if this is a false positive - since most examples of reading a file into a string using istreambuf_iterator do it this way.

This seems to only happen since gcc-12.

probably obvious - but removing -Wnull-dereference removes the issue :p

@康桓瑋 - yes agree - this only happens on my newer compilers -  I have the same code running fine on slightly older compilers.

I seriously suspect this is a gcc bug.

@康桓瑋 I am starting to think that also ... good to know you do as well :)

Bug filed. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=115067

Why are you asking the same question twice when this has already been asked by you in an Old gcc bug also reported on SO 6 months ago. Did you perhaps forgot about that you asked about exactly the same bug in one of your question before?

Bug since gcc 12 (still present in gcc 14) https://godbolt.org/z/5shMn6z8M not using optimization silence this warring.

@user12002570 - I did, sorry, not sure how I didn't find that in my search - but totally had forgotten about it.

@code_fodder I see.
